# How to send raw velocity commands to joints of pr2

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to send raw velocity commands to joints of pr2 instead of high level joint action commands.
I want to apply a reinforcement learning to pr2 arm manipulation. So I need to send raw velocities to pr2 gazebo simulator.

I googled and found that I can use [robot_mechanism_controllers/JointVelocityController](http://robot_mechanism_controllers/JointVelocityController)

But I don't know how to use it to send a velocity command to /r_shoulder_pan_joint.
Could anyone provide me with a simple command line example to publish a such command?

I am testing this on pr2_gazebo for now. I hope a solution would work on gazebo, too.

And are there better ways to send raw velocities rather than robot_mechanism_controllers/JointVelocityController?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259746/how-to-send-raw-velocity-commands-to-joints-of-pr2/) by [JollyGood](https://answers.ros.org/users/985/jollygood/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could finally publish raw joint velocity command to a joint. Here are what I did:

- create a parameter yaml file as follows; e.g. l_shoulder_pan_velocity_controller.yaml

> l_shoulder_pan_velocity_controller:
> type: robot_mechanism_controllers/JointVelocityController
> joint: l_shoulder_pan_joint
> pid:
> p: 5.0
> i: 20.0
> i_clamp: 100.0

- Then load the file on the parameter server

```
$ rosparam load l_shoulder_pan_velocity_controller.yaml
```

- Load the joint velocity controller

```
rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manger load l_shoulder_pan_velocity_controller
```

- Stop the l_arm_controller which is running

```
rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager stop l_arm_controller
```

- Start the joint velocity controller for l_shoulder_pan_joint

```
rosrun pr2_controller_manager pr2_controller_manager start l_shoulder_pan_velocity_controller
```

- Publish joint velocity command topic

```
rostopic pub -1 l_shoulder_pan_velocity_controller/commad std_msgs/Float64 1.0
```

---

Originally posted by [JollyGood](https://answers.ros.org/users/985/jollygood/) with karma: 58 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0